# em.remove(data) instead em.remove(em.merge(data)) in what situation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

So far, I thought, the method find () gives us the comfort that we have just this moment manageable entities.

I know that merge() returns manageable entities, but why in this case it is needed?

```
public void delete(int id) throws DatabaseException {
    Project data = em.find(Project.class, id);
    if(data == null) {
        throw new NotExistsException("id");
    }
    em.remove(em.merge(data));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work without the `em.merge(data)`? I don't see a reason for it to fail.

Comment: Is it not working with `em.remove(data)`?

Comment: Objects from "find" are in managed state, as per the spec. So what happens when you call "remove" with one of those? if an exception then be kind enough to actually state the exception+stacktrace

Comment: It was just a question.The code works.
So the method find () also returns manageable entities, and you can safely use only em.remove (date), right?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing transactions...

If you Start the Transaction at the begin of the method and commit it after em.remove, it should work.